# Is a JSON header really necessary?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, header

Do I really need to define on the header that the output is going to be JSON string or it is completely safe to remove the header line?

```
<?php

//header("Content-type: application/json");

$arr = array    (
                'item1'     =>  "I love jquery4u",
                'item2'     =>  "You love jQuery4u",
                'item3'     =>  "We love jQuery4u"
                );

echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

Comment: Try it and see what happens?

Comment: My question is to check if I'm missing something... It might work now but in other situation not...

Comment: If you remove it, the browser will probably read the document in HTML quirks mode. It will usually work, but there's no point trying to break stuff - leave it in, so the browser understands the document type correctly.

Comment: what prompted this question in the first place?

Comment: CURIOSITY... :) If it's working without... Why bother ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's necessary. It's there to tell the client what content it should expect and parse.

Many clients (like popular browsers for instance) will have some sort of fail safe mechanism in place when content-type header and actual content does not match. In this case it sort-of works - but you should not rely on it.